# How to avoid users getting 500 Errors when server throw exception

Tags: security, exception, error-handling, xpages

I get the following errors in my server log.

- 2012-03-06 09:20:43   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
- 2012-03-06 09:20:43   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0229E: Security exception occurred servicing request for: /demo.nsf/home.xsp - HTTP Code: 500. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in D:/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs

The user only sees this in the webbrowser (source)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title></head>
<body text="#000000">
<h1>Error 500</h1>HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception</body>
</html>
```

So I can tell by the server log that there is a security exception thrown at the server, probably because I have wrong settings in my java.policy file. but my issue is not what is causing the error, but rather how can I avoid users getting these ugly 500 errors.

I would like the error page I have set in the application to be presented to the user just like any other exception.

possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more try/catch blocks you have in your code, the better (within reason, of course):

```
try {
 // code that might throw an error
} catch (e) {
 // examine the error to see if there's a workaround
 // if not, log it and inform the user
} finally {
 // any code that needs to run whether or not there was an error
}
```

This way if something fails, it fails gracefully. Just be sure to make it obvious to the user that something went wrong (and, preferably, provide them instructions they can actually follow up on)... failing silently is even worse than an ugly error page if something went wrong and the user thinks everything was fine.

P.S. As Stephan indicates, there are some errors that simply can't be caught. If the XPage wasn't signed by someone with access to run XPages, for instance, it never even gets to the point of trying to run your code... the page itself is invalid, so there's nothing you can do at runtime. Always make sure that your XPages are signed during deployment.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of errors that "break through" even if you have an error page defined. E.g. when you drag a control onto itself. Security seems another area. All of them are stuff you should handle in development. I haven't seen errors that "typically" happen (true runtime after development completed and tested type of errors) escaping a custom error page. Other than that follow Declan's advice.

Comment: this is not an answer to my question

Comment: Thomas it is: You asked: possible? And I say: NOT for all errors.

There are errors that will throw a 500 error - and you can't do anything about it. So make sure you have tested the apps.

Comment: well, I may not understand this voting thing and I could care less about people getting high or low scores here. I clicked the down arrow because I was not happy with the answer. it turned out when I restarted my http task the 500 error went away. like magic. so this was nothing I could have controlled during my development. sorry for downvoting. I really enjoy the discussion. I did not think people would get upset with it.

Comment: Thomas, it's okay to downvote, but use it for answers that completely miss the question or that are off topic. That was not the case here. It's nicer to up vote or "mark as answer" to pick out the correct one and leave the incorrect answers alone. I try to up vote on-topic answers that teache me something. As a token of appreciation to the other person for taking the time to share the knowledge

Comment: What would be an interesting exercise for the XPages community:
List the errors that "break through" the definition of an error page. So far we know:
- nesting a custom control within itself
- java security errors
I posted a separate question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595883/what-errors-cant-be-trapped-by-a-custom-error-page

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue like this also where my error page was not being displayed and the error 500 page would display instead.

What I discovered is that there was a problem in my error page also and the renderer therefore can't display the error for the original page and you get the server default error page instead.

The best way to check if this is the cause of your particular issue is to start with a simple error page, no theme, no ssjs libraries, no ssjs code on the page etc, just a blank xpage with some static text to indicate that it is the error page.

Once you can confirm that this is the possible cause of the error 500 then you can start building up that error page and add in the dynamic stuff bit by bit till it is the way you need it.

Comment: My question is not about finding out the cause of the error 500

Comment: @ThomasAdrian Yes, but the ugly 500 error could be because you have an error on the error page itself. In my case I had a function in my error page that did a lookup to another database. If the user wasn't logged in when the error occurred they had no rights to that other database and it generated the ugly 500 error and showed the same security exception in the log.

Answer (score 2):

Dmytro Pastovenskyi has a good article http://dpastov.blogspot.com/2012/01/error-pages-in-domino.html about error pages in Domino.

To be on the safe side I have a static html page saying "An error occured". This page is referenced by the HTTPMultiErrorPage setting in the notes.ini on your server.

Then there is a "HTTP response headers" rule addressing special error codes.

The main problem still is, that these are global settings. So there is no easy way to catch all errors specially for your application. But a least the user don't get this annoying white error page.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with this. Error messages bubbling up from some underlying fault that overrides the defined error page for the application. This is not a nice behavior (from a user perspective) and makes you feel a bit naked. I do understand that it's hard for the application to trap those - but there should at least be a way to customize that message - The default error 500 page is not very useful for a normal user anyway...

The only(?) way to try to avoid that *your* code throws such error (ssjs/java) is to (as Tim Tripcony already mentioned) always use try/catch statements around the code (as you already know :))

getDocumentByUNID() is a "good" example of a method that will cause the ugly (but standard) error 500 page to be displayed instead of the defined one in the app.

As for any other error types (system/security and such) - I don't think it's possible to redirect those to the (by the user) invoked applications error page because they are not invoked from the application but rather before the application is invoked (I hope I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Make a new XPage called error.xsp (for example). Put there some basic info that something went wrong, apologize for that fact and provide few links how to continue with the work (even though his/her data may be lost forever - history.go(-1) usually does not resolve the problem). In the background you can log the error (usage of OpenLog recommended).

Open Application Properties, XPages tab. Uncheck **Display XPages runtime error page**. In the combo **Error page** select your page (error).

Comment: Thomas already has the error page set up. He wants to catch errors that the error page doesn't catch.

Comment: I have learned a lesson to not downvote anything here. but this is not the answer. I already have en error page defined. However some errors like in my case security excpetions on server is ignoring the error page