# What errors can't be trapped by a custom error page?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, xpages

In XPages we can define a custom error page that shows whenever a runtime error (500) occurs in an XPages application. However there is a set of errors that ignore this setting (the more fatal ones). So far I know:

- Nesting a custom control inside itself (runs out of stack probably)
- Java security errors

What other errors are there that "break through the error page"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors in the custom error page also generate the Error 500 condition.

Answer (score 1):

Blank id in a DIV tag will do it as well (SPR SODY8RXCPS is to have designer check for it).

eg.

```
<DIV id=""></DIV>
```

Bad coding anyway, id shouldn't be there or have a value.

Comment: Actually, there are a plethora of good reasons for assigning a static ID to a passthru div. But you're right that there should be no reason to explicitly assign any element a blank attribute value.

Comment: It is the assigning of a null string ( "" ) that is the issue. By default value I meant "any value except null", apologies.

Answer (score 1):

if I type http://www.acme.com/demo.nsf and the demo.nsf database does not exist on server you get an 404 HTTP Web Server: Lotus Notes Exception - File does not exist.

but if you type http://www.acme.com/demo.nsf/home.xsp and the home.xsp does not exist in the database you get HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception or HTTP Web Server: Couldn't find design note even it you have an error page specified

in the old domino development you could create "$$" error pages in both an application and you could also do it per server by putting them in domcfg. but I am not sure if any of these problems will solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that crashes the JVM can not be trapped, f.e. out of memory errors or stack overflows. (You will not be informed about the type of error on the server console if a stack overflow happens).

Comment: Yep - I had that today: a classloader conflict confused the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Page inactive for some time will fail when invoking any event (full/partial refresh) because of session timeout.

`Http Status Code: 400`

Reason: Unknown or unsupported protocol version

This error is not handled by XPages error page.