# Error 500 in each xpage

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I am facing a strange error in xpages. Whenever i preview any xpage in internet explorer I get error 500. I've tried this with new nsf, I created only one blank xpage with no elements and tried to preview, I got the same error.
I've also checked the "Display Xpages runtime error page" in xpages tab in Application Properties section but got the same 500 error.
**(I am working on my local machine)**

Url of my xpage:

```
http://localhost/test/testdb.nsf/testxpage.xsp
```

For every preview attempt log.nsf has below entry

```
04/17/2012 03:24:10 PM  HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception [/test/testdb.nsf/testxpage.xsp] Anonymous
```

Below is the error on ie.

```
Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception
```

Comment: check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581337/how-to-avoid-users-getting-500-errors-when-server-throw-exception

Comment: And maybe this can help you too: http://lotususergroup.org/Submissions.nsf/ContentSpotlight/7575DBD773AE3E7F862579D4003F8DA4/?OpenDocument

Answer (score 6):

- Step 1: Go to the application properties and tick "Show standard error page"
- Step 2: Make sure that your application is build (default autobuild in project is ON, but you never know)
- Step 3: Try project clean
- Step 4: Check the errorlog in data/domino/workspace/log
- Step 5: Post your code here to have a look

Comment: This error is not application specific, i am getting it in every xpage in every application. There is no code as well because i am getting it on blank xpage also(as i've specified in the desc.)

Comment: Do nsf work you put on the server? There is also a workspace/local folder with subdirs for each nsf in designer - if you have no rights there.... could be data being in program files - doesn't belong there

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description most probable reason is security: you have no right to run XPages on the server. Either sign with proper ID or manage to be in "Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker:" field of server document (in Security tab).

Anyway, you should always look for the log mentioned by @Simon McLoughlin.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the stack trace in C:/domino-Data-Directory/IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT  and the most recent xpages_...log file, generally a lot more helpful than the one line errors you get in other places

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Windows Vista/7 then for starting your Lotus Notes, right click on Lotus Notes icon and click on "Run as administrator". It works this way on my local machine. I guess this is due to UAC (User Account Control).

Comment: You can edit your question to include the exact version of Notes (along with fix pack, if any) and the log mentioned by Simon McLoughlin. May be this can throw some more light.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it is your Notes client. Then you need to check with your admin.

Some of the time, We do not have a sufficient privilege for data folder. I am also faced this issue.

Comment: never install DATA inside the program files - the installer default is wrong. Install into userprofiles

Comment: We have to get the full access for our data folder in OS level

Answer (score 0):

Check your server port, probably it may 80. So some your application takes port 80 like face book, skype... So quit that process and try :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Extension library in the application ?
Then you need to do a double installation, both the designer and the Client installation to be able to preview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with my server, I only did what @stwissel suggested and then restarted my server and it all worked, but in your case your running it locally try restarting you PC and hope it works. 
Are you running Quicker? I found this article and thought it might help, http://www.zarazaga.net/web/z.nsf/dx/getting-error-500-on-opening-an-xpage