# HTTP: Missing resource string

Tags: http, localhost, xpages

I am trying to open my `xPages` application on local host but I receive this error:

```
HTTP: Missing resource string
```

When I am running application in the `Notes client`, it works.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you only have the Notes Client installed, not the Designer Client. The Notes Client doesn't come with the nhttp.exe which is used when previewing in a browser. nhttp.exe only comes with the full client or Domino Designer client.

Comment: I try it on different computer where I install client, designer, admin (8.5.3) and after it also extension library. Now I receive Error 500. I tried do things described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190080/error-500-in-each-xpage, but nothing help. Im using Windows 7 and port 80 is free. If I run the xpages, nhttp.exe is running and listening on 0.0.0.0:80. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I copy extension library files to the designer web preview server:

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/response.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=FF8152FA2DEA7106862577A7002C72DE&MainID=319414B3B3926EF1862577A70028DA46